# Access the keys of subdictionaries to get all values for certain keys in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a get request to receive a json file via:

```
my_request = requests.get('example')
dict = my_request.json()
print(dict)
```

This is the result:

```
{'1': [{'nb_visits': 1, 'nb_actions': 5,  'idvisitor': 'abc'}, {'nb_visits': 1, 'nb_actions': 16,'idvisitor': 'def'}], 
'2': [{'nb_visits': 1, 'nb_actions': 12,  'idvisitor': 'ghe'}, {'nb_visits': 2, 'nb_actions': 3,'idvisitor': 'xyz'}]}
```

Now I am trying to access the key of the subdictionaries. For example I want a  list with all visitor ids.

Googling gave me this syntax to access the subdictionaries:

```
print(dict[1]['idvisitor'])
```

but this returns a key error for 1

An example end result I would be interested in is to have a list of all idvisitor across all subdictionaries.

Comment: `1` is not `"1"`. json dictionaries cannot have integer keys, only strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print([i['idvisitors'] for i in dict['1']])
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def']
```

**Edit:**

```
print([y['idvisitors'] for x in dict.values() for y in x])
```

Comment: Will do, one more quick question when I already have you here, is there a way to easily replace the dict['1] part to loop through all the 'outter' dicts?

Comment: @Tim So you mean to have `'2'` values also?

Comment: Yes, basically have for all possible outter dicts the idVisitors in one list

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to read it as a dictionary. Now the keys values are the list. You can get value from the list of dictionaries.

```
> for key,value in dict.items():
>     print(value[1].get('idvisitor'))
```